# SQL - Condition to flag more than 1 column is not null

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table has 10 columns. Col1, Col2...Col10

Only one of them should have a numeric value > 0 in it. If more than 1 has a value > 0, then I want to create an error. How can I setup a condition to do that?

Where Col1 is > 0 and Col2 = 0, Col3 = 0, Col4 = 0...
Because there are too many columns, the manual way of writing every scenario is too much code.

What is a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: This sounds a little like an XY problem, if I am honest.

Comment: What do you mean "create an error"?  That is not a SQL operation.

Comment: It is strange that your many columns are thus dependent on each other. Sounds a bit like an inappropriate data model to me, but that's only guessing. What do the columns represent?

Comment: You title says "is not null" and your description says "greater than zero". These are different conditions.

Comment: You title and your explanation are different as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `apply`:

```
select t.*,
       (case when s.col > 2 then 'ERROR' else 'OKAY' end) as status
from t cross apply
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from (values (t.col1), (t.col2), . . . ) v(col)
      where col > 0
     ) s
```

You can adjust the `where` clause to count non-NULL values or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

A check constraint to ensure not more than one column has a value greater than zero could look like this:

```
alter table mytable add constraint check_my_columns
  check 
  (
    case when col1 > 0 then 1 else 0 end +
    case when col2 > 0 then 1 else 0 end +
    case when col3 > 0 then 1 else 0 end +
    case when col4 > 0 then 1 else 0 end +
    ...
    <= 1
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the Cols are type Bit (can hold 0 or 1)

You can sum all the columns and if you get a value > 1 then show the error message

Ex:
if (isnull(col1,0) + isnull(col2,0) + isnull(col3,0) + ... + isnull(col10,0) > 1)
begin
    Show error message
    Return;
end